# Python Fabric return value on remote run command

Tags: python, linux, remote-access, fabric

I'm using run command from python fabric to execute a script remotely.

```
C = fabric.Connection('ip', user='user', connect_kwargs={"password": "password"})
try:
   r = C.run('python3 ~/script.py')
   if r:
        print('{} SUCCESS'.format(C.host))
        break
   else:
        print('{} ERROR'.format(C.host))
        break
except:
    print('{} ERROR'.format(C.host))
```

My script.py is:

```
def download_file(url, filename):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        # Open file and write the content
        with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            # A chunk of 128 bytes
            for chunk in response:
                file.write(chunk)
        return 1
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        return 0

download_file(url,filename)
```

When I execute a run command, is there a way to see, which value was returned in my function, 1 or 0?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

According to the Fabric 2.x docs, results are by default captured and made available under `stdout` and `stderr` attributes on a result: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.0/getting-started.html#run-commands-via-connections-and-run

```
r = C.run('python3 ~/script.py')
print(r.stdout)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `run` command returns a [`Result`](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/api/runners.html#invoke.runners.Result) object, which has the following properties (amongst others):

- *stdout* - the standard out
- *stderr* - the standard error
- *exited* - the exit code for the program
- *ok* - exited == 0
- *return_code* - an alias for exited

so you need to check the `exited`/`return_code` property.

However, your script does not exit with the return code of the function. For this you need to `sys.exit` with that value, so altering the download_file to:

```
sys.exit(download_file(url))
```

would get you the return code from the download_file function. You would need to `import sys` on the script to ensure you have the `sys` module available.

When the program fails with a non-zero exit code, an `UnexpectedExit` exception is thrown. In order to get the exit code in that case you can either (a) capture the exception, or (b) pass in the parameter `warn=True` to the run command, so the run command would look like:

```
r = C.run('python3 ~/script.py', warn=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

However, if i do `sys.exit(download_file(url,filename))`, and then execture the `run` command, I get a _bad command exit code_. Should I work around that?

Comment: You need to pass in `warn=True` to the run command to disable the triggering of the Exception in the case of the command failing. I've updated the answer with that detail.